# Customised running sum query

Tags: sql, sum

I need a query to find running sum, but not sum further if the sum is positive and it should restart when a negative number comes.

Input table

```
  row_number Id value
    2 1 -377  
    3 1 100  
    4 1 -4003 
    5 1 507  
    6 1 3774 
    7 1 499  
    8 1 511  
    9 1 -5000
    10 1 300  
    11 1 100
```

Output Table

```
  Id value running_sum
    1 -377      -377
    1 100      -277
    1 -4003     -4280
    1 507      -3773
    1 3774       1
    1 499       500
    1 511       1011
    1 -5000    -5000
    1 300       -4700
    1 100       -4600
```

I have written query as

```
select *,sum(value) over (partition by id order by row_number rows betwwen unbounded preceding and current row) as running_sum 
from table1;
```

So this sums all and I'm unable to restart the sum when negative number comes at row number 9.

Comment: Please include the expected output, along with your attempted query.

Comment: Why don't you show what you tried so far?

Comment: I suspect you have a problem with your scenario.  There's an implicit "arrival sequence" involved in your dataset that SQL won't necessarily handle in the manner you want.  I believe you'll need to make the sequencing of the numbers explicit before you can start to solve the problem.  i.e. there's currently nothing that "tells" SQL that -377 needs to be processed before the 100, before the 4003 (which I think should be -4003?), etc.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen added input and output along with the attempted query

Comment: @user9601310 added row_number in the input table

Comment: @Bharathi I have added the query..can you please help?

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE or some other looping mechanism.  Tag your question with the database you are using.